# Form not showing up correctly (weird spacing) in a table

Tags: html, css, css-tables

I have a form inside a div inside a TD.  If I put the div outside the table, it renders fine, but when I put it inside the table, extra spacing appears at the top and bottom. The form is the correct size, but the wrapping div adCopyInlineEditContainer randomly has more height to it even if I give it height auto.

```
<div class="inlineEditCustomHolder blueBorder" style="top: 0px; left: 102px;"><div class="adCopyInlineEditContainer" style="">
    <form method="POST" class="adCopyInlineEdit">
        <input type="text" data-linetype="title" maxlength="25" data-maxlength="25" class="colorBlue"> <div class="counter"> <span class="ad_title_counter">0</span>/25</div> <br>
        <input type="text" data-linetype="desc1" maxlength="35" data-maxlength="35" class="colorGray"> <div class="counter"> <span class="ad_title_counter">0</span>/35</div> <br>
        <input type="text" data-linetype="desc2" maxlength="35" data-maxlength="35" class="colorGray"> <div class="counter"> <span class="ad_title_counter">0</span>/35</div> <br>
        <input type="text" data-linetype="dispUrl" maxlength="35" data-maxlength="35" class="colorGreen"> <div class="counter"> <span class="ad_title_counter">0</span>/35</div> <br>
    </form>
</div>
<div class="grid-handle" style="top: 176px; left: 256px;">
</div>
</div>
```

I don't think including my CSS will be too relevant except my input are `display:block` and `position:absolute`.

Any thoughts? You can see in the picture the weird space on the top and bottom.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Get this code

```
 <div class="inlineEditCustomHolder blueBorder" style="top: 0px; left: 102px;"><div class="adCopyInlineEditContainer" style="">
                            <form method="POST" class="adCopyInlineEdit">
                                <input style="float:left" type="text" data-linetype="title" maxlength="25" data-maxlength="25" class="colorBlue"> <div class="counter"> <span style="float:left" class="ad_title_counter">0</span>/25</div> <br>
                                <input style="float:left" type="text" data-linetype="desc1" maxlength="35" data-maxlength="35" class="colorGray"> <div class="counter"> <span style="float:left" class="ad_title_counter">0</span>/35</div> <br>
                                <input style="float:left" type="text" data-linetype="desc2" maxlength="35" data-maxlength="35" class="colorGray"> <div class="counter"> <span style="float:left" class="ad_title_counter">0</span>/35</div> <br>
                                <input style="float:left" type="text" data-linetype="dispUrl" maxlength="35" data-maxlength="35" class="colorGreen"> <div class="counter"> <span style="float:left" class="ad_title_counter">0</span>/35</div> <br>
                            </form>
                        </div>
<div class="grid-handle" style="top: 176px; left: 256px;">
</div>
</div>
```

**See the demo :** http://jsfiddle.net/r6jeE/